# Error trying to upload pandas DataFrame to Netezza

Tags: python, sql, pandas, upload, netezza

I have a pandas DataFrame `'df'` that I'm attempting to upload to a Netezza database.  I've been attempting this using `DataFrame.to_sql` and creating the appropriate `SQLAlchemy` engine to do so:

```
import pandas
import sqlalchemy
import urllib

def upload_test(data, table):
    quoted = urllib.quote_plus('DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};Server=SERVER;Database=DATA_BASE;UID=uid;PWD=pwd;Port=5480;')
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))
    data.to_sql(name=table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        'VAR1': pandas.Series(['2016-05-01', '2016-05-02'])
        , 'VAR2': pandas.Series([2500, 2500])
        , 'VAR3': pandas.Series([211232, 211232])
    }
)
upload_test(data=df, table='TABLE')
```

This just returns a SQL error in my console's Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-68-b2d5c19f9472>", line 19, in <module>
    upload_test(data=df, table='TABLE')
  File "<ipython-input-68-b2d5c19f9472>", line 4, in upload_test
    data.to_sql(name=table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1003, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 569, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1240, in to_sql
    table.create()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 685, in create
    if self.exists():
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 673, in exists
    return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1263, in has_table
    schema or self.meta.schema,
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1972, in run_callable
    return conn.run_callable(callable_, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1477, in run_callable
    return callable_(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py", line 1466, in wrap
    tablename, dbname, owner, schema, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py", line 1475, in _switch_db
    return fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\base.py", line 1621, in has_table
    c = connection.execute(s)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 914, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1341, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 200, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python_2_7_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 450, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] ERROR:  \'SELECT [COLUMNS_1].[TABLE_SCHEMA], [COLUMNS_1].[TABLE_NAME], [COLUMNS_1].[COLUMN_NAME], [COLUMNS_1].[IS_NULLABLE], [COLUMNS_1].[DATA_TYPE], [COLUMNS_1].[ORDINAL_POSITION], [COLUMNS_1].[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH], [COLUMNS_1].[NUMERIC_PRECISION], [COLUMNS_1].[NUMERIC_SCALE], [COLUMNS_1].[COLUMN_DEFAULT], [COLUMNS_1].[COLLATION_NAME] FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] AS [COLUMNS_1] WHERE [COLUMNS_1].[TABLE_NAME] = NULL AND [COLUMNS_1].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = NULL limit 0\'\nerror           ^ found "[" (at char 8) expecting an identifier found a keyword (27) (SQLPrepare)') [SQL: u'SELECT [COLUMNS_1].[TABLE_SCHEMA], [COLUMNS_1].[TABLE_NAME], [COLUMNS_1].[COLUMN_NAME], [COLUMNS_1].[IS_NULLABLE], [COLUMNS_1].[DATA_TYPE], [COLUMNS_1].[ORDINAL_POSITION], [COLUMNS_1].[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH], [COLUMNS_1].[NUMERIC_PRECISION], [COLUMNS_1].[NUMERIC_SCALE], [COLUMNS_1].[COLUMN_DEFAULT], [COLUMNS_1].[COLLATION_NAME] \nFROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] AS [COLUMNS_1] \nWHERE [COLUMNS_1].[TABLE_NAME] = ? AND [COLUMNS_1].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = ?'] [parameters: (u'TABLE', u'dbo')]
```

I know the connection is solid because I've been able to use it to read back data just fine:

```
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 100")
for row in result:
    print row
```

Now from what I've seen on other sites, the issue lies in my choosing of the dialect for my SQLAlchemy engine, but I'm not certain if this is the issue.  Is there some other object I could possibly convert the DataFrame to?  Should I attempt to insert a row at a time into the table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is, as you guessed, in your choice of dialect for SQLAlchemy.

From the last line of your error output:

```
...found "[" (at char 8) expecting an identifier found a keyword...
```

It's delimiting your column and table names with square brackets, which is a MSSQL-ism, and Netezza will not accept that.

I don't have any experience with SQLAlchemy, but if it doesn't have a Netezza-specific dialect to choose, then try one of the Postgres dialects, as this is in Netezza's family tree.